# vim <C-S-Key> mapping

Tags: vim, mapping

I am working with Cygwin/Mintty/Vim.

With `<C-v>` I see that `<C-S-c>` is encoded `<83>`. This mean vim can read it and I can map it using the map command.

Unfortunately if I try:

```
 :inoremap <C-S-c> foobar
```

it doesn't work...

How can I make it work and why vim refuses to map Unicode keystokes?

Same question for `<C-S-F1>`. If I execute this command:

```
 :inoremap <C-S-F1> foobar
```

I will get something like this:

```
[20;5~[20;5~[20;5~[20;5~[20;5~[20;5~[20;5~[20;5~[20;5~[20;5~[20;5~[20;5~[20;5~[20;5~[20;5~[20;5~[20;5~[20;5~[20;5~[20;5~[20;5~[20;5~[20;5~[20;5~[20;5~[20;5~[20;5~[20;5~[20;5~[20;5~[20;5~
```

Where `F1` is `[1;5P` and `F9` is `[20;5~`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Vim apparently does not support exotic key combinations involving Control (`<C-…>`). That includes <kbd>F1</kbd> – though your other attempted mapping <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>C</kbd> *is* supported (and is equivalent to Control with just <kbd>C</kbd>). From a post by [Tony Mechelynck](http://vim.1045645.n5.nabble.com/template/NamlServlet.jtp?macro=user_nodes&user=28373) on [a forum thread “Mapping ctrl-; (ctrl semicolon)”](http://vim.1045645.n5.nabble.com/Mapping-ctrl-ctrl-semicolon-tp1193549p1193550.html):

> The only printable keys which can reliably be used with Ctrl, with
>   predictable results, in cooked mode on any OS, are those defined by
>   ASCII, and that means the following AND NO OTHERS:
>
> - ASCII characters 0x40 to 0x5F (i.e. uppercase A to Z, plus the six
>     nonalpha characters at-sign, left-bracket, slash, right-bracket,
>     [caret] and underscore), where Ctrl subtracts 0x40, thus mapping them
>     to 0x00 to 0x1F respectively. This explains why Ctrl-[ means Esc, Ctrl-I
>     means Tab, Ctrl-M means Enter, etc.
> - Lowercase letters, whose Ctrl counterpart is the same as for the
>     corresponding uppercase (thus Ctrl+letter and Ctrl+Shift+letter are
>     always the same for a given letter)
> - In addition, Ctrl-? is mapped to 0x7F (DEL).
>
> Vim may or may not see other Ctrl-combinations, but that depends on the
>   terminal, and in most cases it won't see them, or confuse them with
>   something else such as the same key without Ctrl.

As for your `<C-S-c>` mapping, I’m not totally sure why you can see `<C-S-c>` with [`<C-v>`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/insert.html#i_CTRL-V) but you can’t map it. When I test in MacVim (a GUI), I get the character `^C` when I try `<C-v><C-S-c>`, and `:inoremap <C-S-c> foobar` works. When I test in OS X’s Terminal, the Terminal swallows the keystroke and beeps, with both `<C-v>` and `:inoremap`. In both cases, `<C-v>`’s behavior is consistent with [`:inoremap`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/map.html#:inoremap)’s, so I don’t know why you are seeing the discrepancy.

Answer (score 2):

Due to the way that the keyboard input is handled internally, this unfortunately isn't generally possible today, even in GVIM. Some key combinations, like <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + non-alphabetic cannot be mapped, and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + letter vs. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + letter cannot be distinguished. (Unless your terminal sends a distinct *termcap* code for it, which most don't.) In insert or command-line mode, try typing the key combination. If nothing happens / is inserted, you cannot use that key combination. This also applies to `<Tab>` / `<C-I>`, `<CR>` / `<C-M>` / `<Esc>` / `<C-[>` etc. (Only exception is `<BS>` / `<C-H>`.) This is a known pain point, and the subject of various discussions on vim_dev and the #vim IRC channel.

Some people (foremost Paul LeoNerd Evans) want to fix that (even for console Vim in terminals that support this), and have floated various proposals, cp. http://groups.google.com/group/vim_dev/browse_thread/thread/626e83fa4588b32a/bfbcb22f37a8a1f8

But as of today, no patches or volunteers have yet come forward, though many have expressed a desire to have this in a future Vim 8 major release.

Comment: thanks but it seems you put this answer everywhere (you actually answered exactely the same to three different questions). Some map like `<C-S-Tab>` works perfectly in my vim...

Comment: Right, I'm using this standard answer to convince Bram, Vim's creator, to address this common point of pain and confusion. Sorry for "polluting" your question; I hope you've still gotten some information out of it, even though it's not a solution to your problem.

Comment: If it's for a good cause I forgive you. I've also asked Bram about this. Perhaps we have better to wait for Neovim (http://neovim.org/)